# A fly sits on the outside surface of a cylindrical drinking glass . It must crawl to another point situated on inside of the glass . Find the shortest

Tags: geometry, geodesic

A fly sits on the outside surface of a cylindrical drinking glass . It must crawl to another point situated on inside of  the glass . Find the shortest path possible(neglecting the thickness of the glass).

I am not quite getting wont it be equal to $2a$ where $a$ is the distance of the fly from the upper circular boundary of the cylinder.However, if that point is not situated exactly to its initial position, in that case i think the shortest path will be from the point of position to the upper corcular boundary($a$) of the cylinder and then from that upper circular boundary to the desired point i.e those two are connected by a straight line , so that it is $x$(say), so the total shortest path is $a+x$....

Comment: Shortest distance would be $2a$ only in case the goal spot on inside of glass just happened to be exactly on the other side of the glass surface from where the fly was initially. But the goal spot on the inside would typically not be at that special position.

Comment: @coffeemath Yeah, I assumed that special point...but also the question requires any point inside the cylinder...so in that case i think the shortest path will be from the point of position to the upper corcular boundary($a$) of the cylinder and then from that upper circular boundary to the desired point i.e those two are connected by a straight line , so that it os $x$(say), so the total shortest path is $a+x$....

Comment: I don't get your last comment. If the fly goes straight up to a point on the rim, it is only when the goal position is on the same vertical of the cylinder that the fly should go directly down the inside from where he gets to on the rim. If the goal position is *not* on that vertical then the shortest path will not be along straight lines but along the curved cylinder surface in some way for both the path on the outside to a point on the rim and then from there inside the glass to the goal point..

Comment: @coffeemath What do u mean by curved cylinder surface? Do u mean the outer curved part ...then it is the part where the  fly was present initially and then he goes to the upper circular path through a straight line and then after reaching there it might not go through the vertical,  if the destination point does not lie in that vertical but still... wherever it goes we can connect that particular point with the point in the upper circular part ....

Comment: @coffeemath ... As going through any other way say ...from the upper circular part $P$ to the the point $B$ (an arbitary point in the interior of the cylinder) and then to the desired point $C$ then we have the triangle inequality $PB+BC>PC$ so, $PC$  must be shortest which is a straight line from the upper circular part to the desired point inside the cylinder ..

Comment: Try to draw a straight line from P to C for the case of the cylinder in xyz space given by $x^2+y^2=1, 0 \le z \le 1$ [where the rim is the intersection of the cylinder with the plane $z=1$] in the case of starting point $P=(1,0,0)$ to goal point $B=(-1,0,1/2).$ It cannot be done. Such a shortest path from P to Q in this case must travel from along curved paths in the cylinder along one curved path from P to some point on the rim and another curved path from that rim point to the goal Q.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135612/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-franklin).

Comment: If the bottom of glass is dry and free to move, this fact changes general form of answer adding choice of one of two options depending on some relation of input data.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to stretch your intuition for this problem is to take $2$ equal sized pieces of paper, and designate them as P1 and P2.

Roll P1 and P2 both into cylinders, where in both P1 and P2, the right edge of the paper just meets the left edge.  So, P1 and P2 should now represent cylinders that have equal heights and equal radii.

On P1, mark any **arbitrary** outer-starting point, on the outside of the cylinder, with a pen.  Also, mark any **arbitrary** inner-ending point, on the inside of the cylinder, with a pen.  On P2, mark the exact same
inner-ending point, on the inside of its cylinder, to correspond to the inner-ending point of P1.

Unwrap P1, so that it is now flat on a table, with the side containing the outer-starting point face up.

Unwrap P2, so that it is now flat on the same table, with the side containing the inner-ending point face up.

Place P2 directly above P1, but upside down, so that (in effect) the top edge of P1 is edge-to-edge with what represents the top edge of P2.

Draw the line from the (now visible) outer-starting point on P1 to the inner-ending point on P2.  This represents the shortest distance possible between the arbitrarily selected outer-starting point, and inner-ending point.

For the portion of the path that is on P2, trace the same path on the underside of P1, where the underside contains the inner-ending point.

Now, take P1 and roll it back into the cylinder.  The path that has been inked in on the outside and inside of P1 represent the path that must be followed to minimize the route going along the surface of the P1 cylinder, from the outer-starting point to the inner-ending point.

Answer (score 0):

Using cylindrical coordinates $(r, \phi, z)$, let coordinates of $A$ be

$A = (R , \phi_1, z_1) $

and let the cylindrical coordinates of $B$ be

$B = (R, \phi_2, z_2) $

And let the height of the cylindrical glass be $H$.  What you need to do is reflect point $B$ about the plane $z = H$, then its image would becomes

$B' = (R , \phi_2 , 2 H - z_2 ) $

Now the shortest distance between $A$ and $B'$ is by Pythagorean theorem equal to

$ D = \sqrt{ R^2 (\phi_2 - \phi_1)^2  + (2 H - z_1 - z_2)^2 } $